# how can does one declare a sub-class object inside of a base class without leading to recursion errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to structure a Python 3 program as follows:

**Base Class**: Body

**Sub-Class**: Head

A super-simple code representation is as follows:

```
class Body:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head_obj = Head()
        # ...Set-up body...

    def body_actions:
        print('Body does something')


class Head(Body):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...Set-up head...

    def head_actions:
        print('Head does something')
```

I want to be able to create an instance of Body called 'body_obj' and then access the Head sub-class (and its properties/methods) as follows:

```
body_obj = Body()
body_obj.body_actions()
body_obj.head_obj.head_actions()
```

However, when I run the code, Python returns a maximum recursion depth RuntimeError.

I need to do some setup with __ init __ in both the Body and Head classes, and Pycharm complains when I don't call a super() function within the Head class's __ init __ as this appears to be bad practice.

What is the proper way to set up this kind of structure where a Class's sub-objects all need to be initialized when the base class is instantiated?

I have looked into nesting the classes, but this also appears to be poor practice.

Comment: That's not what inheritance means. "Subclass of X" doesn't mean "part of X"; `class Head(Body)` means that a head *is* a body.

Comment: You are abusing the inheritance semantics. A body is *composed* of a head (and other body parts), a head *is not* a body. If what you mean by "nesting classes" is "composition", then *no, it is not a poor practice at all*. Most people would agree that you should prefer composition over inheritance, and indeed, there are extremist views that say *never use inheritance, always use composition*. You are *mixing* inheritance and composition in a fundamentally broken way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A head is not a *kind* of body, it's a *part* of the body AFAIK.

So you should be using *composition* instead of *inheritance*:

```
class Head:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...Set-up head...

    def head_actions():
        print('Head does something')

class Body:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Head()
        # ...Set-up body...

    def body_actions:
        print('Body does something')
```

Now you can do:

```
body = Body()
body.body_actions()
body.head.head_actions()
```

The reason you get infinite recursion is that your `Body` is the superclass of `Head`, so when you call `super().__init__()` you instantiate a `Body`, which in your implementation creates a `Head`, which calls `super().__init__()` and so forth.

Composition (if that's what you mean by 'nesting') is not bad practice, it's standard practice and often makes more sense than inheritance.

---

**Edit in response to comment**

To access the `Body` methods from the `Head` you can pass a reference to the `Body` on creation. So redefine the classes as follows:

```
class Head:
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body

    def head_actions():
        print('Head does something')

class Body:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Head(self)

    def body_actions:
        print('Body does something')
```

Now you can access the head from the body and the body from the head:

```
body = Body()
head = body.head
head.body.body_actions()
```

Or even

```
body.head.body.body_actions()
```

Comment: Using this answer, how can the Head class access the properties and methods of the Body, if needed? For example, let's say that Body has a method called "sun_tan()" which can act on the whole Body or just parts of it?